# How to use maven package a war with taglibs like jstl and spring?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, taglib

maven+spring boot

when I type mvn spring-boot:run

that is ok without anyerror

but when I type mvn package

server throws a exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

my pom

and I want to know what should I do to resolve this problem

any master can help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project mlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
<!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
<dependencies>
    <!--developing a web application -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Import Spring Boot’s default HTTP engine (Tomcat) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Support for common test dependencies, including JUnit, Hamcrest and 
        Mockito along with the spring-test module. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<!--To add this blowe to create an executable jar -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding below dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
   <version>Your Security Version</version>
</dependency>
```

Another point to be noted, instead of **mvn mvn package** type **mvn package**

Comment: It's already work ,but not with your dependency, I added this below`<!-- Compile -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>`